# Evaluate shell source block on spacemacs

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-babel

I'm new to spacemacs. I did a fresh install following [these instructions](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs#default-installation). When i try to evaluate a `shell` src block, i get the following message:

```
org-babel-execute-src-block: No org-babel-execute function for sh!
```

- I tried adding the following lines inside `~/.spacemacs` under `defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()`:

  ```
  (with-eval-after-load 'org
     (org-babel-do-load-languages
     'org-babel-load-languages
     '(
       (python . t)
       (sh . t)))
    )
  ```
- Tried `shell` or `bash` instead of `sh` in the above code (replacing the language identifier in the src block respectively).
- Also tried adding the above code without the `with-eval-after-load 'org` under `defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()`
- When i do `M-x load-file` i get a `done` message, but when I try  `M-x dotspacemacs/sync-configuration-layers` i get this message:

  ```
  helm-M-x-execute-command: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, ob-bash
  ```

---

- Spacemacs v.0.300.0
- GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0) of  2020-11-30

Comment: What does `C-h v org-babel-load-languages` give you as the value of the variable?

Comment: Try `(shell . t)` instead of `(sh . t)` . The name of the library is `ob-shell`.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to reply. I solved it using this [FAQ](https://www.spacemacs.org/doc/FAQ.html#how-to-fix-symbols-value-as-variable-is-void-errors-on-startup). Deleted the `.emacs.d/elpa` directory and set `dotspacemacs-elpa-https` to `nil` and now it works good.